# Django 1.8 IntegrityError when adding new user

Tags: django

I moved an old Django app from 1.4 to 1.8 and everything in the main application ran fine. I then needed to copy everything from server 1 to server 2, and in the process just dumped the mysql data for the admin database and installed to the new database.

Everything came up fine, however when creating a new user I get:
IntegrityError at /admin/auth/user/add/
(1048, "Column 'last_login' cannot be null")

This is a live system with 30 accounts. I found a variety of solutions to this online but I want to make sure it doesn't trash my database.

I only need the admin database fixed up. My business side database and tables are not managed by Django, but is a custom schema (that I inherited).

btw, deleting a user works fine.

Answer (score 0):

This is [described in the release notes](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/releases/1.8/#abstractuser-last-login-allows-null-values), along with the steps to migrate your database to allow null values:

> The `AbstractUser.last_login` field now allows null values. Previously, it defaulted to the time when the user was created which was misleading if the user never logged in. If you are using the default user (`django.contrib.auth.models.User`), run the database migration included in contrib.auth.
>
> If you are using a custom user model that inherits from `AbstractUser`, you’ll need to run makemigrations and generate a migration for your app that contains that model. Also, if wish to set `last_login` to NULL for users who haven’t logged in, you can run this query:
>
> from django.db import models
>      from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
>      from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractBaseUser
>
> ```
> UserModel = get_user_model()
> if issubclass(UserModel, AbstractBaseUser):
>     UserModel._default_manager.filter(
>         last_login=models.F('date_joined')
>     ).update(last_login=None)
> ```

Your error suggests that you haven't run the migration that will allow null values for that column.